# Handling exception in Service layer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

Could you please advice how to overcome the problem which is described below:

There is an application (it involves using Hibernate and Spring frameworks) with 3 layers: DAO, Service and Controller. I want to avoid saving duplicate entities in DB. I made it by using constraints at DB-level and in annotation in bean (`@Table(name = "artist", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "artist_name")})`).
The logic supposes that if I try to add duplicate entity an exception is thrown. I try to process exception in service layer but it fails to succeed. I mean that even when I explicitly notice all the exception which are thrown an application can't proceed to work because of exceptions. To be more clear I cite the code below:

**DAO-layer**

```
@Override
public void saveEntity(Client client) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(client);
}
```

**Service-layer**

```
@Transactional
@Override
public boolean saveEntity(Artist entity) {
    boolean completedState = false;
    try {
        //method from DAO-layer
        artistDAO.saveEntity(entity);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException | UnexpectedRollbackException e) {
        return completedState;
    }
    return completedState = true;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="addArtist", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processNewArtistForm(@ModelAttribute Artist artist, Model model) {
//If duplicated artistName prompts to be saved an saveEntity(entity) returns "false". Entity is failed to save.
    boolean completedState = false;
    completedState = artistService.saveEntity(artist);
    if (completedState == true) {
        List<Artist> listOfArtists = artistService.getListOfEntities();
        model.addAttribute("listOfArtists", listOfArtists);
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "An artist under present name already exists");
        return "newArtist";
    }
    return "listOfArtists";
}
```

**Tomcat's notification when I try to save duplicate entity**

```
Type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:720)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.saveEntity(Unknown Source)
    web.ArtistsListController.processNewArtistForm(ArtistsListController.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.9 logs.
```

Could you please advice if these architectural solution is correct or not? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to check for duplications before saving?:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void saveEntity(Client client) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    // session.get() will always query the database and will return null
    // if no rows found
    if (session.get(Client.class,client.getId()==null) {
    session.save(client);
    //flush session cache
    session.flush();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not I answered about. Your code checks if the entity has an id (in other words if an entity ia already in db or not). But I try to avoid save object if the same one is already in db. In my case an entity has unique constraint (artistName-property). When I save new entity (which is in transient state) with the name-property equals to the name that any persistent object may has - an exception is thrown. So, the issue is in how to process these exception correctly.

Comment: Well, then check by this constaint, not just with id. The idea was to avoid usage of exception throwing-catching as part of business logic.

Comment: I got it. You are right - it will work out. But I want to find out how to process the exception in my case.

Comment: As I suppose you're catching wrong exception type, replace with RuntimeException in catch block and dump actual exception class

Comment: I tried to notice Exception in catch-block but it didn't help. I realised that the problem is in transactions propagation. I found a pieces of advice at stackoverflow but they didn't work out for me. Anyway thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

By default, @Transactional annotation results in a transaction which rollbacks on any RuntimeException (see the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings)).

Use `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {ConstraintViolationException.class})` to change the behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it doesn't work. I tried to notice this at DAO-layer as well as at Service - but I catched the same exceptions.

Comment: Hmm, would you provide your configuration of transaction manager?

Comment: Wabi, I've just found a solution - I had to flush the session. As one of way out is to handle exception in controller. In this way there are no exceptions in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solution - is to process exception in controller. Also (frankly, I still can't understand why it works) I could just flush the session.